# How to embed WebView inside InputView For IOS custom keyboard app extension

Tags: ios, webview, custom-keyboard

I tried creating a storyboard with webview embedded into it
then in ViewController controller class, inside **viewDidLoad method**:

```
[self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]]];
```

**logs:**

```
CustomKeyboard[1865:37706] [Common] BKSAccelerometer unable to create notifyd token for device orientation


CustomKeyboard[1865:37779] [default] error registring notify port: (1000000)


CustomKeyboard[1865:37706] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash_libsystem libsystem simulate crash failed "libsystem_network.dylib: networkd_settings_setup_notify_watch :: notify_register_dispatch(com.apple.system.networkd.settings) [status 1000000] failed"


CustomKeyboard[1865:37706] [] networkd_settings_setup_notify_watch notify_register_dispatch(com.apple.system.networkd.settings) [status 1000000] failed, dumping backtrace:

        [arm64] libnetcore-856.1.8

    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188db5534 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 116

    1   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dd17e4  + 332

    2   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dd15b0  + 68

    3   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188da91a8 nwlog_is_debug_logging_enabled + 32

    4   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dc8fac  + 256

    5   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dc917c  + 24

    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000188c051c0  + 16

    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000188c12860  + 84

    8   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dc7088  + 160

    9   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dc6b1c  + 136

    10  libsy


CustomKeyboard[1865:37706] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash_libsystem libsystem simulate crash failed "libsystem_network.dylib: networkd_settings_init :: notify_register_check(nw_notification_name_settings) status 1000000 token -1 failed"


CustomKeyboard[1865:37706] [] networkd_settings_init notify_register_check(nw_notification_name_settings) status 1000000 token -1 failed, dumping backtrace:

        [arm64] libnetcore-856.1.8

    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188db5534 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 116

    1   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dd1620  + 180

    2   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188da91a8 nwlog_is_debug_logging_enabled + 32

    3   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dc8fac  + 256

    4   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dc917c  + 24

    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000188c051c0  + 16

    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000188c12860  + 84

    7   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dc7088  + 160

    8   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dc6b1c  + 136

    9   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000188dc68c4 nw_path_create_evaluator_for_endpoint + 972




CustomKeyboard[1865:37912] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1


CustomKeyboard[1865:37912] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2


CustomKeyboard[1865:37912] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3


CustomKeyboard[1865:37912] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:5 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted


CustomKeyboard[1865:37912] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceCreateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)


CustomKeyboard[1865:37945] [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 2 Connection has no connected handler


CustomKeyboard[1865:37929] PAC stream failed with


CustomKeyboard[1865:37929] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork: -72000


CustomKeyboard[1865:37929] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1


CustomKeyboard[1865:37929] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2


CustomKeyboard[1865:37929] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3


CustomKeyboard[1865:37929] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:5 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted


CustomKeyboard[1865:37929] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceCreateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
```

Comment: I've got a similar problem trying embed a contacts view controller into the custom keyboard. What iOS version is your simulator/test device?

Comment: I was testing it on ios 10

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Any luck @ShubhamJha ? Also having this problem

Comment: Try the following solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place the code in **viewDidAppear Method** instead of **viewDidLoad** method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    //CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 800)];
    NSString *urlString = @"http://mum00blf.in.oracle.com:7777/index/public/login.html";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];


    /*dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self.view addSubview:webView];
    });*/

    [self.view addSubview:webView];

}
```